# What special meaning does -RELEASE suffixed versions carry for Maven, if any?

Tags: maven, release, gradle

When I release versions of projects, I usually go the short, easy route: it will be 1.0, 1.1, etc etc; while development versions are `-SNAPSHOT` suffixed.

For one of my project, someone once asked me why my "official" versions were not suffixed with `-RELEASE` because that was the company's policy...

I *do* know of projects which suffix official versions like these. But does it really make a difference to Maven, or some other mechanism linked to it?

(I *did* search around but didn't find any answer to that one -- let alone a conclusive one)

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but I know that e.g. Spring uses the RELEASE suffix as well as MS and RC suffixes to denote milestones and release candidates such as 3.0.0.RC1, 3.0.0.RC2, 3.0.0.M1, ...). It seems to be a convention to denote artifacts and not to "burn" release numbers.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Maven downloads `-SNAPSHOT` dependencies by default on every build from remote repositories, since being snapshots they're supposed to be changing often, while `-RELEASE` artifacts and "regular" version numbers, i.e. with no suffix, are not re-downloaded on every build since they're supposed to be stable.

Comment: Uh, you mean that if I specify `1.0` and there is a `1.0-SNAPSHOT` available, the latter will be picked instead? That is not quite my experience...

Comment: no, i mean that if you specify `1.0-SNAPSHOT` as a dependency version it will be redownloaded on every build, while specifying `1.0` will download version 1.0 only on the first build (if it's not already present in the local repo)

Comment: Aaah, OK. Now _that_ is an interesting piece of information... I'll +1 your answer if you update your answer with this. I didn't know it worked this way!

Comment: Snapshots aren't redownloaded on every build. By default, both Gradle and Maven cache snapshots for 24 hours, then check if a newer one is available.